# Magento2: Issue during config shipping methods - blocks hidden

Tags: magento2

When i try configure shipping methods after select this tab. Blocks They appear on the second and disappear. How to solve it?

[image]

M 2.3.4

log:

```
[2020-04-10 18:55:43] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js' [] []
[2020-04-10 18:55:43] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js' [] []
[2020-04-10 18:55:47] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js' [] []
[2020-04-10 18:55:47] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js' [] []
```

Comment: Check log file for error

Comment: I have update my topic

Comment: Use this command - php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: This command not solve our issue. We try some times regenerate css etc